# Bitcoin not showing up on Armory

Tags: armory

I have transferred 1 BTC from JAXX Wallet to Armory. But it is not showing up on Armory.

The transaction was confirmed so I know it was delivered to my Armory wallet but I can't see or access it on Armory.

Can anyone tell me what I should do?